# How can I check to see if two dates are within a certain date range in a SQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SearchCreatedAssignments]
(@LessonName NVarchar(MAX), @DateFrom date, @DateTo Date, @LocationCode NVarchar(MAX))
As 
BEGIN 
Select *
from dbo.CreatedAssignments
--IsNull replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.
--IsNull(check_expression, replacement_value)
--NullIf returns a null value if the two specified expressions are equal.
--In other words, NULLIF returns the first expression if the two expressions are not equal. 
--If the expressions are equal, NULLIF returns a null value of the type of the first expression. 

where LessonName   = IsNull(NullIf(@LessonName,''),LessonName) 
 AND  StartDate    = IsNull(NullIf(@DateFrom,''),StartDate) 
 AND  EndDate      = IsNull(NullIf(@DateTo,''),EndDate)
 AND  LocationCode = IsNull(NullIf(@LocationCode,''),LocationCode)
 AND status ='a'

END
```

As you can see, this stored procedure is set up so that users can search by any one search criterion, or any combination of search criteria (the criteria being the column names), while leaving the other criteria blank. For instance, suppose a user wanted to search the database by only `lessonname`. This stored procedure allows the user to do just that. It will return all results that match the specified `lessonname`, regardless of the fact that the other criteria are left blank. So, here is my question: how can I preserve this logic, but return results where the `startdate` and `enddate` fall within a certain date range? I know that I need to use the `between` keyword, but I'm not sure how to implement this change while preserving the logic as it stands. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mysql or sql-server.... looking to dbo. you are using sql-server.. please fix the correct tags

Comment: Oops. My mistake. Thank you.

Comment: I think you can use Dynamic Sql. Just combine query string. Visit this link to refer more, my friend: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the start date and end date to fall within the *same* range of dates -- i.e. your @DateFrom and @DateTo parameters -- you can do it like this:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SearchCreatedAssignments]
(@LessonName NVarchar(MAX), @DateFrom date, @DateTo Date, @LocationCode 
NVarchar(MAX))
As 
BEGIN 
Select *
from dbo.CreatedAssignments
--IsNull replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.
--IsNull(check_expression, replacement_value)
--NullIf returns a null value if the two specified expressions are equal.
--In other words, NULLIF returns the first expression if the two expressions     are not equal. 
--If the expressions are equal, NULLIF returns a null value of the type of     the first expression. 

where LessonName   = IsNull(NullIf(@LessonName,''),LessonName) 
 AND  StartDate    BETWEEN IsNull(NullIf(@DateFrom,''),'1901-01-01') AND IsNull(NullIf(@DateTo,''),'2199-01-01')
 AND  EndDate      BETWEEN IsNull(NullIf(@DateFrom,''),'1901-01-01') AND IsNull(NullIf(@DateTo,''),'2199-01-01')
 AND  LocationCode = IsNull(NullIf(@LocationCode,''),LocationCode)
 AND status ='a'

END
```

Note that I changed the second parameter of your IsNulls to use scalar values rather than the actual columns.  I did this to prevent issues when one date parameter is left blank, which could leave you with comparative dates in the wrong order (e.g. StartDate BETWEEN 1/1/2017 AND 1/1/2015).

Comment: I believe this is what I was looking for. Would you mind explaining the logic here? So far in testing, I'm quite certain it is working like I had expected; I just need to wrap my mind around what is going on logically.

Comment: It checks to see if the start date and end date are each (individually) between the `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo` parameters.

If `@DateFrom` is null or is an empty string, it substitutes `1/1/1901`.  If `@DateTo` is `null` or is an empty string, it substitutes `1/1/2199`.  So for example, if the procedure is executed with a `@DateFrom` of `6/2/2017`, but `@DateTo` is left blank, the procedure will check to see if both the start date and end date are `between 6/2/2017 and 1/1/2199`.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use between operator on each field.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SearchCreatedAssignments]
(@LessonName NVarchar(MAX), @DateFrom date, @DateTo Date, @LocationCode NVarchar(MAX))
As 
BEGIN 
Select *
from dbo.CreatedAssignments
--IsNull replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.
--IsNull(check_expression, replacement_value)
--NullIf returns a null value if the two specified expressions are equal.
--In other words, NULLIF returns the first expression if the two expressions are not equal. 
--If the expressions are equal, NULLIF returns a null value of the type of the first expression. 

where LessonName   = IsNull(NullIf(@LessonName,''),LessonName) 
 AND  (StartDate BETWEEN  @DateFrom AND @DateTo) AND 
 AND  (EndDate BETWEEN  @DateFrom AND @DateTo) AND
 AND  LocationCode = IsNull(NullIf(@LocationCode,''),LocationCode)
 AND status ='a'

END
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. Your answer fails to return results when other criteria are left blank.